# Query to get Oracle DB version

Tags: sql, oracle, version

I'm looking for a way to get an Oracle DB Server version as "X.Y.Z".

I can use a query from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba004.htm#ADMIN11039), but it will show a version of not just a server.

I can use `v$version` view but the resulting string will contain much more than just "X.Y.Z".

Is there a simple way to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just query v$instance?

```
SQL> select version from v$instance;

VERSION
-----------------
12.2.0.1.0
```

No need to muck around with pl/sql or called procedures.

Comment: 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Answer (score 23):

**SQL**

```
SELECT version FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
 WHERE product LIKE 'Oracle Database%';
```

Result:

```
VERSION
----------
18.0.0.0.0
```

18c/19c: `VERSION_FULL` also shows the installed release update

View V$INSTANCE (Requires SELECT privilege on SYS.V_$INSTANCE):

```
SELECT version FROM v$instance;
```

DBA_REGISTRY (Requires SELECT privilege on SYS.DBA_REGISTRY):

Shows the version for each installed component.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_registry 
 WHERE comp_id = 'CATALOG';
```

**PL/SQL**

```
DECLARE
   l_version       VARCHAR2(20);
   l_compatibility VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   DBMS_UTILITY.DB_VERSION(l_version, l_compatibility);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_version);
END;
/
```

Result:

```
18.0.0.0.0
```

Still shorter:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION|| '.' || DBMS_DB_VERSION.RELEASE);
END;
/
```

Result:

```
18.0
```

Comment: @ThomasKirchoff, the op says SQL not PL/SQL. And the third solution gives more than just one record.

Comment: @Igor I have fixed the query (OracleXE returns only one record). I left the PL/SQL part and added another way using SQL.

Comment: To cover "Personal Oracle Database" it should be LIKE '%Oracle Database%'  (with leading percent)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';

Comment: I can't use it - it gives much more than X.Y.Z